# How to make Spring Boot API accept a client's custom 'x-www-form-urlencoded' format for the nested objects parsing

Tags: java, node.js, json, spring-boot, x-www-form-urlencoded

The Spring boot API could not parse the x-www-form-urlencoded type request since the client posted the data differently than what Java supports.

The incoming request body looks like below:

**DeliveryPostCode**=TEST123000&**EnableCOD**=false&**Basket**%5B0%5D%5B**Id**%5D=383293820&**Basket**%5B0%5D%5B**Category**%5D=Smartphone

In which a Basket is an object which has Id, Category as fields.
Decoding the above URL gives -

```
DeliveryPostCode=TEST123000&EnableCOD=false&Basket[0][Id]=383293820&Basket[0][Category]=Smartphone
```

which does not work for **Java**
If we can get a request which looks like below, It works for Java -

```
DeliveryPostCode=TEST123000&EnableCOD=false&Basket[0].Id=383293820&Basket[0].Category=Smartphone
```

Since the client is something which we cannot afford to change. We have to do some manipulation in  Java before Controller takes this
**OR**
a modify in middleware node js layer we have between client & server which acts as a proxy.

Please suggest.

Comment: I have not had to use one before, but I think you could use a Spring [Handler Interceptor](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor-vs-filter) for this.

Comment: Thanks, David for the suggestion. Yes, this is one option that we are already exploring. Either a filter or interceptor can transform the incoming request body to the way Java supports it. Please suggest if there is any other efficient way to handle this